# SVG circle does not appear when in a <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I've written a javascript code to help me create interactive maps. I click on the map and click on the button and then it writes an *a* tag with a *href* into the *svg* tag of the map, into this *a* tag a circle is added. However, the circle does not appear at this moment.

[Here you can see an image of the interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHngL.png)

But if I use the developing tools of Google Chrome, delete the circle, and the rewrite the circle exactly like it was just before, it works.

```
var svgmap = document.getElementById("mapsvg");
var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
var atag = document.createElement('a');
atag.setAttribute("href",url);
circle.setAttribute("cx",posX);
circle.setAttribute("cy",posY);
circle.setAttribute("r",4);
circle.setAttribute("stroke","black")
svgmap.appendChild(atag);
atag.appendChild(circle);
```

And then this is added :

```
<svg id = "mapsvg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"  viewBox="0 0 700 700" xml:space="preserve">
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">
    <circle cx="343" cy="303" r="4" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="green" class="dot">
    </circle>
</a>
</svg>
```

It looks like it's a problem of "refreshing". I just learned HTML and Javascript so I have no idea where the problem is !

Comment: You are mixing HTML and SVG incorrectly. Although there is an `a` tag in svg it is not the same as an HTML `a` tag

Comment: I used this tutorial from Mozilla Firefox https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/a. In this one they use the a tag like I did...

Comment: Yes, but it is used in a different way and you can't just use html `document.createElement` as this is for html items only. You will need to use `document.createElementNS` as per @Oliver 's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cx` and `cy` attributes on the `circle` are the centre x-y coordinates. This means that the centre of your circle is `[343, 303]` from the top-left of the SVG element. Anything outside of the SVG will not be visible, so if those coordinates are greater than the width or height of the SVG, the circle will appear outside of the SVG bounds.

Your SVG does not have any width of height dimensions, nor a viewBox, meaning that the circle has coordinates well outside of the viewBox/width/height.

You should either try setting a width/height to the SVG, or a viewBox (in the format `viewBox ="0 0 100 100"`, for example) and setting the `cx` and `cy` of the circle within the viewBox.

Something like:

```
svgmap.setAttribute("width", (posX * 2));
svgmap.setAttribute("height", (posY * 2));
svgmap.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 " + (posX * 2) + " " + (posY * 2));
```

Might do the trick.

**Edit:** As Lee Taylor says above, whilst the `<a>` tag is a HTML element too, within an SVG it has a different meaning, and should be created the same as other SVG elements. So whilst creating an `a` tag within `document.body` would be:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
```

For an SVG, you would need to change `var atag = document.createElement('a')` to be:

```
var atag = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'a');
```

Comment: I actually put a viewport ! It's my first question on Stackoverflow so I didn't know if I had to simplify my code or not, but I will edit it. And when I delete and rewrite the same line in the developing tools the circle is visible at the right place, so it seems good...

Comment: Sorry, meant `viewBox`, not `viewport` - edited to reflect me mixing up my terms :)